# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - Jest, Typescript with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I get this nasty error when i try to run 'npm test',
the command in package.json is the following, "test": "jest --config ./config/jest/jest.config.ts",

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
  1 | import axios from 'axios'
> 2 | import qs from 'query-string'
```

The component where the test should be running is using third part libraries as you can see,
here my configuration of jest.config.ts

```
import { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest/dist/types'

const options: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    rootDir: '../../',
    collectCoverage: false, // temporal
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/config/jest/jest.setup.ts'],
    coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
       lines: 90,
    },
 },
 //transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
}

export default options
```

components that don't use third part libraries i don't get any kind of error, like Button.tsx, Input.tsx, etc...

The problem occurs when i tried to test SignUp.tsx (who use a axios client as you can see), so, i haven't found a solution to this in any site. please help!!!

i tried a lot of solutions, creating babel.config.js, .babelrc, transform, transformIngore etc..,

Comment: In this case, I would mock the third party. Because you should test only your code, not the one coming from the third party.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the library `'query-string'`, it looks like doesn't work well with `jest`, so I changed the version to `7.x`.